# Sliding panel menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a sliding panel menu that works ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephmoreland/3BT7t/)), but I can't wrap my head around shortening the jQuery for it. Right now, when you click one of the links on the left, I wanted it to show that link's `div` and hide the others, which I've done, but I don't understand how I can make it more efficient. I'd like any "shown" `div`s to be hidden and then show the `div` associated to that link.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="work">
    <ul id="gallery">
      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="toggleWidth1">RETAIL</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="toggleWidth2">HEALTH CARE</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="toggleWidth3">POWER &amp; INFRASTRUCTURE</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="toggleWidth4">MANUFACTURING</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="toggleWidth5">FOOD &amp; BEVERAGE</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="toggleWidth6">CULTURAL &amp; COMMUNITY</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="workDiv">
      <div id="workDiv_retail">
        <h3>RETAIL</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="workDiv_healthcare">
        <h3>HEALTH CARE</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="workDiv_power_infrastructure">
        <h3>POWER &amp; INFRASTRUCTURE</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="workDiv_manufacturing">
        <h3>MANUFACTURING</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="workDiv_food_beverage">
        <h3>FOOD &amp; BEVERAGE</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="workDiv_cultural_community">
        <h3>CULTURAL &amp; COMMUNITY</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.toggleWidth1').click(function () {
    $('#workDiv_healthcare').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_power_infrastructure').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_manufacturing').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_food_beverage').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_cultural_community').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_retail').slideToggleWidth();
});
$('.toggleWidth2').click(function () {
    $('#workDiv_retail').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_power_infrastructure').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_manufacturing').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_food_beverage').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_cultural_community').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_healthcare').slideToggleWidth();
});
$('.toggleWidth3').click(function () {
    $('#workDiv_retail').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_healthcare').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_manufacturing').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_food_beverage').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_cultural_community').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_power_infrastructure').slideToggleWidth();
});
$('.toggleWidth4').click(function () {
    $('#workDiv_retail').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_healthcare').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_power_infrastructure').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_food_beverage').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_cultural_community').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_manufacturing').slideToggleWidth();
});
$('.toggleWidth5').click(function () {
    $('#workDiv_retail').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_healthcare').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_power_infrastructure').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_manufacturing').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_cultural_community').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_food_beverage').slideToggleWidth();
});
$('.toggleWidth6').click(function () {
    $('#workDiv_retail').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_healthcare').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_power_infrastructure').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_manufacturing').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_food_beverage').slideLeft();
    $('#workDiv_cultural_community').slideToggleWidth();
});

jQuery.fn.extend({
  slideRight: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).animate({width: 'show'});
    });
  },
  slideLeft: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).animate({width: 'hide'});
    });
  },
  slideToggleWidth: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      var h = $(this);
      if (h.css('display') == 'none') {
        h.slideRight();
      } else {
        h.slideLeft();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: A few comments - avoid using ids, prefer using classes that describe the elements to prevent weird conflicts. Also, don't include the element type in the id/classname, there's no point in that. Finally, the more common convention is to separate words with hyphens over underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the `href` the `id` of the element you wish to `show` you can simplify it greatly.

This works since you use the structure of your document to your advantage you know you want to `hide` all the `<div/>` child elements under `#workDiv` regardless of the `id` and only want to show the `<div/>` of the `<a/>` you clicked on.  And since the `<a/>` contains a `href` that links to the `<div/>` you want to show you can simply retrive that value and show the correct element.

**`<html/>`**

```
<ul id="gallery">
  <li><a href="#workDiv_retail" class="toggleWidth" >RETAIL</a></li>
  <!-- the others...-->
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.toggleWidth').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#workDiv > div").slideLeft();
    $(id).slideToggleWidth();     
});
```

**[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/3BT7t/9/)**